# How do I get Mod Loader for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have tried to find a download for mod loader but no one seems to have it. I've had no luck finding a download or following video tutorials to help.

I want to get the Explosives+ mod so would be grateful if someone could provide a link to a compatible modloader.

Answer (score 5):

[Rigasumi's Modloader](http://www.minecraftdl.com/risugamis-modloader-1-3/).

[Minecraft Forge Modloader](http://files.minecraftforge.net/).

[Magic Launcher](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/939149-launcher-magic-launcher-114-mods-options-profiles-news/).

I use a combination of Magic Launcher and Forge, which works very nicely, but Rigasumi's modloader has a very good reputation. These links should take you to the most up-to-date locations of the downloads.

Comment: The forge modloader can do everything Risugami's modloader can. ANd since it is packed together with forge, it can do all the things forge can and Risugami's modloader can't. SO I suggest using that one.